# Rest API or Soap webservice

Tags: wcf, c#-4.0, asp.net-web-api2, wcf-security, wcf-rest

I am unclear about which webservice to use. Within an organisation network a webservice needs to be built to download document (pdf) and XML data.

The service operations are

- Login - (input UserName,API version) Returns (Some static Data and
  GUid generated using .Net)
- GetCarList - (input SessionId(Guid),ModelID) Returns (Car XML) - We
  have Car xsd to build Car Object
- GetDocument - (input SessionId(Guid), docID) Return pdf file

It is sure that this service is not going to run over https. Can we use rest services(WebAPI 2)/WCF rest 4.0 or it is better to use WCF services (Soap over http) from security and validating XML point of view?

Comment: You can have security and XML validation in both.

Answer (score 2):

After some more reading i guess WCF or WebAPI both can be used. Rest Service has more broad reach as it  leverages HTTP protocol. Since the requirement is stateless and doesn't involve transactions WebAPI seems more apt then WCF.